# comparing MapReduce to cloud database services

Tags: database, hadoop, cloud, distributed-computing

Are the databases offered by cloud services such as [Windows Azure SQL Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336239.aspx) or [AWS Big Data](http://aws.amazon.com/big-data/) capable of distributed computing, in the sense that the query optimizer divides the work across servers which compute in parallel, similar to how MapReduce distributes computation across nodes?

I haven't found anything about any such query optimization in the [Azure documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188721%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), although [PDW](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/solutions-technologies/data-warehousing/pdw.aspx) seems like it may do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS has EMR (Elastic Map-Reduce) which is Hadoop provisioned by AWS.

Azure has HDInsights which is Hortonwork's data platform (Hadoop) installed on Windows VMs.

Microsoft's PDW (parallel data warehouse) doesn't support map-reduce right as far as I know but they are working on it (http://www.zdnet.com/microsofts-polybase-mashes-up-sql-server-and-hadoop-7000007424/) - PDW is essentially a few SQL Server machines with a central management layer that allows partitioning and distribution of the data between the different nodes - it can and will break a query between the PDW nodes if the data resides on more than one but the parallelism is not map-reduce in nature.